# How to handle multiple card views / buttons on a fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, onclicklistener, android-cardview

I have multiple card views in my Main Fragment that go to different fragments within the app usin  onClickListener functionality.

However, when the cardviews are selected the fragment that shows is always the last replaced.

Ex: In main activity all the card views, when selected, show the affirmations fragment. No matter if they have been connected to their proper fragment.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCardSelected() {
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new ProfileFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new BibleFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new ShopFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new NotiFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new CalFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new AffFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

MainFragment.java

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
private onFragmentBtnSelected listener;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);
   CardView clickCardProfile = view.findViewById(R.id.cardProfile);
   CardView clickCardBible = view.findViewById(R.id.cardBible);
   CardView clickCardShop = view.findViewById(R.id.cardShop);
   CardView clickCardNoti = view.findViewById(R.id.cardNotifications);
   CardView clickCardCalendar = view.findViewById(R.id.cardCalendar);
   CardView clickCardAffirmations = view.findViewById(R.id.cardAffirmations);

  /*Button clickme = view.findViewById(R.id.clickHF);
   clickme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           listener.onBtnSelected();
       }
   });
   return view;*/
   clickCardProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           listener.onCardSelected();
       }
   });
   //return view;
   clickCardBible.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           listener.onCardSelected();
       }
   });
   //return view;
   clickCardShop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onCardSelected();
        }
    });
   clickCardNoti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onCardSelected();
        }
    });
   clickCardCalendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onCardSelected();
        }
    });
   clickCardAffirmations.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onCardSelected();
        }
    });
   return view;
}
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context){
    super.onAttach(context);
    if(context instanceof onFragmentBtnSelected ){
        listener =(onFragmentBtnSelected) context;
    }
    else {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement listiner");
    }
}
public interface onFragmentBtnSelected{
    //public void onBtnSelected();
    public void onCardSelected();
}
```

Would I need to create an interface method for each of the buttons, and separate the respective  replace statements or is there a way to have them all in the same method and switch from fragment to fragment?